# Can you explain what while(*++str1) and return (str1 - str2) does?

Tags: c, while-loop, c-strings, strlen, function-definition

In this context, does the `while` loop work like a `for` loop? Also, what does the `str1-str2` string subtraction result in?

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int fun(char *str1) { 
    char *str2 = str1; 
    while (*++str1);   
    return (str1 - str2); 
} 

int main() { 
    char *str = "GeeksQuiz"; 
    printf("%d", fun(str)); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66418287/edit) the question to include your own work that you need help with.

Comment: Subtracting one pointer from another gives the number of *elements* that separate them, but they must both point to the same *object* (or one element past it) to be valid arithmetic. Similar to array indexing, where `array[42]` is the 43rd *element*, not necessarily the 43rd *byte*.

Comment: If you copied this code from somewhere, which I'm nearly 100% sure you did based on the fact the string is `GeeksQuiz`, _please cite your source by pasting the URL into your question._

Answer (score 3):

Notice that you are working here with pointers and not strings, so starting from the end, `str1-str2` is a pointers arithmetic.
As you know string should be ended with a null, so in the memory "GeeksQuiz" is actually an array of chars that has the next values: GeeksQuiz\0. In that way, `while(*++str1);` will run through the values of this array till it reaches \0.
To conclude, this function will return the number of chars in the string.

Comment: "*will return the number of chars in the string*" Or UB if `str1` points to an empty string.

Comment: What does UB stand for?

Comment: Undefined Behavior @WolfgangRoth

Comment: *this function will return the number of chars in the string.* I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the function is to calculate the length of a string. That is this while loop

```
while(*++str1);
```

iterates until the terminating zero character `'\0'` is encountered. It is supposed that after the while loop the pointer `str1` will point to the terminating zero character `'\0'` while the pointer `str2` will point to the beginning of the string due to the initial assignment

```
char *str2 = str1;
```

So the difference  `str1-str2` will yield the length of the string. The length of a string is determinate as the number of characters in the string before the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

However the function has a bug.  If the user will pass an empty string `""` that is internally represented as a character array with one element that is equal to the terminating zero character `{ '\0' }` then the function invokes undefined behavior. So an empty string contains in its first character the terminating zero character `'\0'`.  However in the while loop the pointer `str1` at first incremented and then already the next character is checked whether it is the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

That is this while loop

```
while(*++str1);
```

may be rewritten the following way

```
while ( ( ++str1, *str1 != '\0' ) );
```

As it is seen at first the pointer str1 is incremented.

Apart from this defect the function parameter should have the qualifier `const` because within the function the passed string is not being changed. Also the return type of the function should be unsigned integer type as for example size_t (it is the return type of the standard C string function `strlen` that does the same task.)

The function can be declared an define the following way

```
size_t fun( const char *s ) 
{ 
    const char *t = s;
 
    while( *t ) ++t;
   
    return t - s; 
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t fun( const char *s ) 
{ 
    const char *t = s;
 
    while( *t ) ++t;
   
    return t - s; 
} 

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "";
    printf( "The length of the string \"%s\" is equal to %zu\n", s, fun( s ) );
    
    s = "1";
    printf( "The length of the string \"%s\" is equal to %zu\n", s, fun( s ) );

    s = "12";
    printf( "The length of the string \"%s\" is equal to %zu\n", s, fun( s ) );

    s = "123";
    printf( "The length of the string \"%s\" is equal to %zu\n", s, fun( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The length of the string "" is equal to 0
The length of the string "1" is equal to 1
The length of the string "12" is equal to 2
The length of the string "123" is equal to 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code through `clang-format` [see Note 1] to confirm what I suspected about the weird `while` loop you've got going on there, and I came up with this as correct formatting for your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun(char *str1)
{
    char *str2 = str1;
    while (*++str1)
        ;
    return (str1 - str2);
}

int main()
{
    char *str = "GeeksQuiz";
    printf("%d", fun(str));
    return 0;
}
```

Personally, I would have written it like this though, to make the `while` loop super obvious. You can run this code here: https://onlinegdb.com/BkxlKb75GO.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun(char *str1)
{
    char *str2 = str1;
    while (*++str1)
    {
        // do nothing 
    }
    return (str1 - str2);
}

int main()
{
    char *str = "GeeksQuiz";
    printf("%d", fun(str));
    return 0;
}
```

Even more-readable, however, is this for the `fun()` function, which I've also renamed to `count_num_chars_in_str()`:

```
int count_num_chars_in_str(char *str1)
{
    char *str2 = str1;
    while (*str1 != '\0')
    {
        str1++;
    }
    return str1 - str2;
}
```

A shorter name might be `num_chars_in_str()`, `str_length()`, or `strlen()`. `strlen()` already exists ([see here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen)), and this is precisely what it does. It can be included by header [`string.h`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/), and is part of the C and C++ standard. Here's its description [on cplusplus.com](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/):

> `size_t strlen ( const char * str );`
> Get string length
> Returns the length of the C string str.
>
> The length of a C string is determined by the terminating null-character: A C string is as long as the number of characters between the beginning of the string and the terminating null character (without including the terminating null character itself).
>
> This should not be confused with the size of the array that holds the string.

So, running any of these programs above, the output is `9`. All the program does is count the number of non-null chars (where a null char is `0`, or `'\0'`--same thing) in the string passed in, which is `GeeksQuiz` in this case. `GeeksQuiz` contains 9 non-null chars.

*Where did you get your code by the way? Please post links and references. You should always reference your sources.*

`while (*++str)` simply keeps incrementing the `str` pointer one char at a time until a null terminator (`0`) is found, which occurs right at the end of the string, after the last char in it. Once that happens, the difference between the two char pointers is taken, resulting in the difference between the address location of the null terminator right *after* the `z`, and the address location of the first char in the string, which is `G`. The difference in memory address between these 2 chars is 9 chars.

Not only is the original version less-readable, it also has a bug in it. For this test case, it should print `0`, but it prints `1` instead:

```
    char *str = "\0";
    printf("%d", fun(str));
```

My more-readable version in `count_num_chars_in_str()` corrects this bug too.

Lesson: don't write unreadable or obfuscated code.

---

[Note 1] The way I ran it through `clang-format` is I just copy-pasted your original code into a `main.c` file, then copied that into my [eRCaGuy_CodeFormatter](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_CodeFormatter) repo here, then ran `./run_clang-format.sh`.

Comment: `(*str1 != NULL)` is incorrect. `NULL` is a null pointer, not a null byte. Use `(*str1 != '\0')` instead. You should only use NULL for null pointers and write *null terminator* or *null byte* for the `'\0'` at the end of a C string.

Comment: @chqrlie, fixed. I suppose `NULL` is usually defined as zero but doesn't have to be, so the other options are more correct. And, `NULL` is intended for use on pointers not for use on the contents of what pointers point to (unless that's also a pointer :)).

Comment: Indeed `NULL` can be defined as `((void *)NULL)` and it must be so defined on architectures where `void *` and `int` have a different representation (eg: `sizeof(void*) != sizeof(int)`) or are passed in a different way to variadic functions or functions without a prototype.

Comment: You might also mention that `fun("\0")` returns `1` but `fun("")` has undefined behavior and explain the difference.

Answer (score 1):

The loop `while (*++str1);` increments the pointer, reads the byte pointed to by the updated `str1`, and tests if this byte is null, if not it stops otherwise do nothing and repeat. This loop would be more readable with an explicit statement instead of an empty statement `;`:

```
while (*++str1 != '\0')
    continue;
```

`return (str1 - str2);` computes the difference of pointers `str1` and `str2` and returns this value as an `int`. The difference of 2 pointers is defined if they point to the same array and evaluates to the number of elements between them.

The function attempts to compute the length of the string argument but would fail for the empty string because `str1` is always incremented before the test, hence would skip the null terminator at offset `0` for the empty string. The behavior is undefined as the code then reads beyond the end of the string. For non empty strings, It prints the number of non null characters, aka the length of the string: `fun("GeeksQuiz")` returns 9.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int fun(const char *str) { 
    const char *start = str;
    while (*str != '\0')
        str++;
    return str - start; 
} 

int main() { 
    const char *str = "GeeksQuiz"; 
    printf("length of \"%s\" is %d\n", str, fun(str)); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> In this context, does the `while` loop work like a `for` loop?

I would say that *all* `while` loops act like `for` loops, and vice versa.

Any time you have a loop

```
while(condition)
    { /* do something */; }
```

you can replace it by an equivalent `for` loop:

```
for(; condition; )
    { /* do something */; }
```

Going the other way, any time you have a `for` loop

```
for(initial_expression; test_expression; increment_expression)
    { /* do something */; }
```

you can (almost) replace it with an equivalent `while` loop:

```
initial_expression;
while(test_expression) {
    /* do something */;
    increment_expression;
}
```

(There's one small difference between the two, but it only shows up if you use a `continue` statement in the loop.)

If you were stranded on a desert island with a broken C compiler (or if you were stranded in the classroom of an instructor who likes to pose "trick" questions), and you had to write a C program without using the `for` keyword, you could: you could write all your loops using `while` instead, without loss of functionality.